# select a row based on the highest value of a column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The `dataFrame` looks something like this: Name of person and weight at a given date.

```
  Name   date      w
1 Mike 2019-01-21 89.1
2 Mike 2018-11-12 88.1
3 Mike 2018-03-14 87.2
4 Hans 2019-03-21 66.5
5 Hans 2018-03-12 57.4
6 Hans 2017-04-21 55.3
7 Hans 2016-10-12 nan
```

I want to select the last time `Hans` has logged in his weight. So the answer would be

```
4 Hans 2019-03-21 66.5
```

Here's what I successfully managed to do:

```
# select Hans data that don't have nans
cond = ( data['Name'] == 'Hans' )
a = data.loc[ cond ] 
a = a.dropna()       

# get the index of the most recent weight
b = d['date'].str.split('-', expand=True) # split the date to get the year
```

now `b` looks like this

```
print(b)
#4 2019 03 21
#5 2018 03 12
#6 2017 04 21
```

how can I extract the row with `index=4` and then get the weight?

I cannot use `idxmax` because the `df` are not `floats` but `str`.

Comment: `df[df.Name.eq('Hans')&df.date.eq(df.date.max())]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `idxmax`, but a workaround is to use NumPy's `argmax` with `iloc`:

```
df2 = df.query('Name == "Hans"')
# older versions
# df2.iloc[[df['date'].values.argmax()]]
# >=0.24
df2.iloc[[df['date'].to_numpy().argmax()]]

   Name        date     w
4  Hans  2019-03-21  66.5
```

Another trick is to convert the date to integer using `to_datetime`. You can then use `idxmax` with `loc` as usual.

```
df2.loc[[pd.to_datetime(df2['date']).astype(int).idxmax()]]

   Name        date     w
4  Hans  2019-03-21  66.5
```

---

To do this for each person, use `GroupBy.idxmax`:

```
df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.date).astype(int).groupby(df['Name']).idxmax().values]

   Name        date     w
5  Hans  2018-03-12  57.4
2  Mike  2018-11-12  88.1
```